# Summing rows of a 2D list without using sum function in python

Tags: python

I have a listed called numbers and I am writing code to sum the rows then sum the result of those sums (i.e. sum the column). I am supposed to write the code without the sum function. What I have so far is pasted below. It gives me close to the right output but is just slightly off and I don’t know what the deal is.

```
total=0

for row in numbers:
  for i in row:
      total+=int(i)
  print(total)

grandtotal=0
for cols in row:
  grandtotal+=total
print(grandtotal)
```

Comment: What's the input? What output are you expecting? What are you actually getting?

Comment: You aren't calculating the sum of each row separately.

Comment: The input is numbers=[1,1,-2][-1,-2,-3][1,1,1].  The output I’m getting is 0, -6, -3 for the sums and -9 for the grand total. I should be getting 0, -6, 3, and -3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `total` back to zero for each row. And since you aren't saving the row totals anywhere you need to accumulate the `grandtotal` at the end of each row loop, not in a separate loop

```
numbers = [
    [1, 1, -2],
    [-1, -2, -3],
    [1, 1, 1],
]

grandtotal = 0
for row in numbers:
    total = 0
    for i in row:
        total += i
    print(total)
    grandtotal += total
print(grandtotal)
```

**output**

```
0
-6
3
-3
```

Comment: LOL, you got it. I’m obvi a newb.